# What is a good way to implement a message board or other common UI plugins

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, user-interface, content-management-system

I am thinking there must be some libraries out there that people have developed which can be used as "plugins" or whatever people call them to do simple and common UI types of things.

I am using the message board idea as just an example, but I am looking for a general solution.  For example, is there a place where I can browse "gems" for RoR that just take care of some UI component?

How do people usually integrate such pieces as a message board present at the bottom of every page, or some other ui tool without writing their own, or using a CMS?

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two good places to browse gems are http://ruby-toolbox.com/ and of course http://rubygems.org/